# Illuminate\Validation\Factory::make(): Argument #1 ($data) must be of type array, App\Models\Product given

Tags: php, laravel, rest, laravel-8

This is my controller function to store a product, i have the error in the $validator, i'm using this in the api route, i have the error of the title, i've try so many things and nothing works, please helpme, if i send in $validator the $req->all() it works, but i need to send a picture and thats why i'm using the $productReq, i'm using laravel 8

```
public function store(Request $req)
    {
        $productReq = new Product($req->all());

        if ($req->file('file') == null) {
            $req->file = "";
        } else {
            $image = $req->file('file')->store('public/images');
            $url = Storage::url($image);
            $productReq->file = $url;
        }

        $rules = array(
            'name' => 'required',
            'price' => 'required',
            'file' => 'required|image'
        );
        $validator = Validator::make($productReq, $rules);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json([
                'error' => true,
                'response' => $validator->errors()
            ], 401);
        } else {
            $product = Product::create($productReq);
            return response()->json([
                'error' => false,
                'response' => $product,
            ], 200);
        }
    }
```

Comment: _"but i need to send a picture and thats why i'm using the $productReq"_ - how is this an issue with validation?

Comment: Also, _"if i send in $validator the $req->all() it works"_ - what doesn't work for you in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Validator::make()` expects an array of data to be provided to it. You've provided an instance of a `Product`, which Laravel doesn't know what to do with.  What you want to do is validate your data before creating an instance of `Product`.

```
public function store(Request $req)
{
    $rules = array(
        'name' => 'required',
        'price' => 'required',
        'file' => 'required|image'
    );

    $validator = Validator::make($req->input(), $rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json([
            'error' => true,
            'response' => $validator->errors()
        ], 401);
    } 

    $product = new Product($req->input());

    if ($req->file('file') == null) {
        $req->file = "";
    } else {
        $image = $req->file('file')->store('public/images');
        $url = Storage::url($image);
        $product->file = $url;
    }

    $product->save();

    return response()->json([
        'error' => false,
        'response' => $product,
    ], 200);
}
```

You can also simplify the controller's logic by making use of some of Laravel's conveniences. However, it may produce responses that do not match what the front end expects (i.e. JSON message when a validation error is encountered).

```
public function store(Request $req)
{
    // Laravel's `validate()` method on a Request will validate against the 
    // current request data and return the valid input. It will throw an Exception
    // if validation fails, which Laravel will handle and reply with the validation errors.
    $validatedInput = $req->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'price' => 'required',
        'file' => 'required|image'
    ])

    $product = new Product($validatedInput);

    // ... file logic

    $product->save();

    // In Laravel, you can return an array from a controller. Laravel 
    // will assume it's supposed to be JSON, and encode it automatically for you
    return [
        'error' => false,
        'response' => $product,
    ];
}
```